# How to get request’s HTTP headers with Socket.io?

Tags: http, express, socket.io

I have an Express app running behind Nginx, so when I try to get the user’s IP, I always get `127.0.0.1` instead of the real one, which is set by Nginx in the `X-Real-IP` header. How do I get this header? Is there a way to have it *via* the `socket` object?

The code would be basically like that:

```
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function( socket ) {

    var ip = /* ??? */;

    /* do something with the IP…

       … some stuff …

     */
});
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To get the IP when you're running behind NGINX or another proxy:

```
var ip = req.header('x-forwarded-for') || req.connection.remoteAddress;
```

or for Socket.IO

```
client.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || client.handshake.address.address;
```

From: http://www.hacksparrow.com/node-js-get-ip-address.html

Comment: Actually this is what I’m using, and it always gives me `127.0.0.1` since this is the proxy’s IP (i.e. Nginx), and the real IP is in the `X-Real-IP` field.

Comment: Ah ok. Try adding `proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;` to your nginx configuration

Comment: Thanks, but my question is about Socket.io, so I don’t have any `req` (nor `res`) object, but a `socket` one :-(

Comment: Gah!! Try client.handshake.headers['x-forwarded-for'] || client.handshake.address.address;

Comment: You should be careful about enabling in your application without first checking what your server will do if a malicious user sends an `X-Forwarded-For` header. It is possible that they could use that to circumvent any IP blocking (or rate limiting) measures in place. For example, it is common for, if the user sets `X-Forwarded-For` to something like `magic` for the `X-Forwarded-For` that your app sees to be `magic, <their actual IP>` Thus, by manipulating headers, a user can "change their IP" without actually changing their IP.